# Text not displaying from WebAPI to Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a call to my WebAPI

```
this.myService.GetEntities().subscribe(data => {           
    console.error(data);
});

GetEntities() : Observable<object[]> {
    const _url: string = this._srvrUrl+ 'api/RefData/GetEntities/';
    return this._http.get(_url).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Then in my API I have this code

```
[Route("api/RefData/GetEntities")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetEntities()
{
    Model.Entities ce = new Model.Entities();
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StringContent("Connection String: " + ce.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "Text/txt");       
    return response;           
}
```

For some reason it is not passing back the connection string to my console when doing the console.error(data);

The return result is this

```
main.90d316cd482b0815f970.bundle.js:1 e {_body: ""1"", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: t, …}
```

In debug mode the _body has the connectionstring and it looks correct, but in production mode the _body has this number of "1". It makes no sense. All I want to do is to find out what connection string value this DBContext Entity has in production so that I can narrow down an issue we are having.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's wrong but I would suggest (1) using the network trace in chrome to see the actual response and (2) returning an object (via `OkObjectResult` or the `Ok(object)` helper method) rather than messing with HttpResponseMessage directly, its much easier to get right.

Comment: Network Trace shows response of "1" . How would I use ObjectResult?

Comment: `return Ok(someObjectWithYourConnectionStringInIt)`. You can also do *just* the string but objects tend to work better when you actually get into angular

Comment: I tried that and it still has the value of "1" in the console. It is making no sense

Comment: Can you edit to show the new code? I'm not sure this is something that can be solved by SO at this point